# How to choose a Wagtail image across a ParentalManyToManyField?

Tags: django, wagtail

### Environment:

Wagtail 1.13

Django Version: 1.11.11

Python Version: 2.7.12

I'm following the [Wagtail documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/getting_started/tutorial.html?highlight=parentalmanytomanyfield#categories) to try to add an image showcase (not a category) to a page using ParentalManyToManyField:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    showcase_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank="true", default="SHOWCASE")
    showcase_images = ParentalManyToManyField('wagtailimages.Image')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('showcase_title'),
        InlinePanel('showcase_images', label="Showcase images", panels=[
            ImageChooserPanel('showcase_images')
        ]),
    ]
```

Everything is fine if I comment out the `showcase_images` editing panel, but I get a KeyError as soon as uncomment the panel `showcase_images`.  In addition to the above variation of editing `showcase_images`, I've also tried simply `InlinePanel('showcase_images')`, `FieldPanel('showcase_images')`, `InlinePanel('showcase_images', label="Showcase images", panels=[ImageChooserPanel('image')])`, and probably another variation or two.  Can someone propose a solution?

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://dev.somedomain.com:8181/admin/pages/3/edit/

Django Version: 1.11.11
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
[u'my_app',
 u'search',
 u'wagtail.wagtailforms',
 u'wagtail.wagtailredirects',
 u'wagtail.wagtailembeds',
 u'wagtail.wagtailsites',
 u'wagtail.wagtailusers',
 u'wagtail.wagtailsnippets',
 u'wagtail.wagtaildocs',
 u'wagtail.wagtailimages',
 u'wagtail.wagtailsearch',
 u'wagtail.wagtailadmin',
 u'wagtail.wagtailcore',
 u'wagtail.contrib.wagtailstyleguide',
 u'modelcluster',
 u'taggit',
 u'wagtailfontawesome',
 u'django.contrib.admin',
 u'django.contrib.auth',
 u'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 u'django.contrib.sessions',
 u'django.contrib.messages',
 u'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
[u'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 u'wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
 u'wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _cache_controlled
  43.             response = viewfunc(request, *args, **kw)

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/urls/__init__.py" in wrapper
  96.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/decorators.py" in decorated_view
  31.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/views/pages.py" in edit
  481.         edit_handler = edit_handler_class(instance=page, form=form)

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py" in __init__
  269.             self.children.append(child(instance=self.instance, form=self.form))

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py" in __init__
  269.             self.children.append(child(instance=self.instance, form=self.form))

File "/opt/virtualenvs/gmmiTMID/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py" in __init__
  693.         self.formset = form.formsets[self.__class__.relation_name]

Exception Type: KeyError at /admin/pages/3/edit/
Exception Value: u'showcase_images'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InlinePanel` doesn't work with `ParentalManyToManyField` relations, only `ParentalKey` relations. You'll need to set up an intermediate model to define the relation between pages and images, like `BlogPageGalleryImage` in the [tutorial's 'images' section](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/getting_started/tutorial.html#images) (but with the `caption` field omitted in this case, so it's just a direct association between pages and images).

(Alternatively, you can use a plain `FieldPanel` with `ParentalManyToManyField`, but this will just give you a set of checkboxes for all images in the system, rather than the the image chooser interface.)